# Существует ли какой-то аналог Volley в Java?

Tags: java, сеть, клиент-сервер, библиотеки, kotlin

Существует замечательная библиотека [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley), позволяющая сильно упростить работу с сетью при разработке приложений для `Android`. Вопрос в том, а существует хоть сколько-то приближенный по простоте аналог этой библиотеки на чистой Java или Kotlin?

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову Apache: https://hc.apache.org/

Comment: @ezhov_da Насколько я знаю, он несколько более низкоуровневый.

Comment: возможно, но использовать его от этого не сложнее, если прямо простейший Http нужен - http://javalite.io/http

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо:)

Comment: Также, можно упомянуть две хорошие библиотеки для работы с сетью и пакетами в Java:  JNetPcap и JPcap. 

Здесь их сравнение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623681/jnetpcap-vs-jpcap

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, это библиотеки для перехвата и анализа пакетов, а мне нужна библиотека для более высокоуровневого  клиент-серверного взаимодействия

Comment: Retrofit смотрели? http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: OkHttp, например

Comment: @temq Retrofit пробовал, мне он показался достаточно отдалённым от того же Volley. Не говоря о том, что сам по себе он не очень хорош (ИМХО).

Comment: @Nofate, OkHttp слишком низкоуровневая, до состояния Volley её придётся доводить своим велосипедом, чего я искренне не хочу.

Comment: Можно узнать в чем по вашему мнению он не очень хорош? И зачем тогда искать альтернативу если все, что не похоже на volley вас не устраивает?

Comment: Избыточная необходимость в использовании аннотаций, что не позвляет менять поведение на лету. Ну то есть если у меня поменяется маппинг для какой-либо команды, я уже не смогу это поменять без перезаливки новой версии приложения и перезапуска. Это то, что всегда и сразу бросается в глаза, когда я пытался его использовать я много чего неудобного нашёл.

Comment: @temq вопрос как раз и состоит в том, чтобы найти аналог Volley. Проблема самой Volley в том, что эта библиотека очень жестко привязана к Android функционалу, а я бы хотел нечто подобное использовать в своих не android проектах.

Comment: При изменении в апи так или иначе придется вносить изменения в код и пересобирать приложение. Аннотации скрывают boilerplate код. Парсинг ответов от сервера можно написать руками без использования аннотаций(если это подразумевается под маппингом который меняется на лету). Ну и так же retrofit не привязан к андройду и его можно использовать в обычных java проектах. Ну раз он вам не подходит, то не буду настаивать.

Comment: > При изменении в апи так или иначе придется вносить изменения в код
Это не всегда так